# Cypress Select Specific Child of HTML <select>

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, cypress

Is there a way in Cypress.io to select a specific child  of a  element as opposed to using the containing text or value? In my case, the data changes and thus the test will break if used with a different set of data that is not hard-coded in.

Comment: Do you want to select the nth child of an element ? If so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50750956/777285). Otherwise please edit your question with more details on what you want to do, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd use `select()` based on index. First you get the `4th` value of the `select`, then use a `.then()` that yields it's `value`:

```js
cy.get('select.myselect option').eq(4).invoke('val').then((val)=>{      
  cy.get('select.myselect').select(val)
})

// .eq(n) yields the nth element
```

Comment: I got this error with this approach: `Error:    CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: 'value' does not exist on your subject.` Instead, I had to replace `its('value')` with `invoke('val')` and then it works. (Cypress 3.1 docs specify using `its()` to get the value of non-function properties, and using `invoke()` to invoke an element's (jQuery) function properties. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html